# Include Sub-Folder?

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, subdirectory

I wanted to make a a BAT-Script which checks 2 folders to see whether  the same files are present in both of them.
This is now working, but I have no idea how to make it so, that it includes all subfolders in the folder.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "ordner1=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test1"
set "ordner2=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test2"

echo Dateien, die in %ordner2% fehlen:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in ("%ordner1%\*") do (
    if not exist "%ordner2%\%%~nxf" (
        echo %%~nxf
        set "fehlende_dateien=!fehlende_dateien! %%~nxf"
    )
)
endlocal & set "fehlende_dateien=%fehlende_dateien%"

echo Dateien, die in %ordner1% fehlen:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in ("%ordner2%\*") do (
    if not exist "%ordner1%\%%~nxf" (
        echo %%~nxf
        set "fehlende_dateien=!fehlende_dateien! %%~nxf"
    )
)
endlocal & set "fehlende_dateien=%fehlende_dateien%"

set /p kopieren="Willst du die fehlenden Dateien kopieren? (ja/nein): "

if /i "%kopieren%"=="ja" (
    for %%d in (%fehlende_dateien%) do (
        copy "%ordner1%\%%d" "%ordner2%\%%d"
    )
)

pause

endlocal
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Please do not post bilingual posts either. Not being a native speaker or very good in English is no problem, someone else can edit the post for linguistical issues.

Answer (score 0):

In order to synchronise Windows directories, you don't need to loop over the files one by one. This can easily be handled, using [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) or [robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).

Comment: but how do i use it? how do i include sub-folder?